# How to make a div into a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I recently started coding and I want to know the best way to make a box into a checkbox. So I want to make a website where the user can choose colors by checking the colored boxes to pick the ones they want. I have researched and can't find a good answer. All the boxes should be clickable, as the user can choose more than one color.

*edit* I'm sorry if I didn't make sense! What I'm trying to do is something like this: [sv.tinypic.com/r/dcelb6/9](http://sv.tinypic.com/r/dcelb6/9). So the boxed are colored, and you can check them.

Here is my html:

```
<div>
          <a href="#" class="color-box black-box" value="0">
            <h3>Black</h3>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="color-box grey-box" value="0">
            <h3>Grey</h3>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="#" class="color-box blue-box" value="0">
            <h3>Blue</h3>
          </a>
        </div>

</div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.color-box {
  width: 15.20833%;
  min-width: 15.20833%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 15.20833%;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 0.72917%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 7px 0.72917%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.color-box h3 {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.black-box {
  background: #000;
}

.grey-box {
  background: #9E9E9E;
}

.blue-box {
  background: #205DB1;
}
```

Comment: You want something like this?http://jsfiddle.net/VvHwm/

Comment: @bellastic, The community wants to help you, and we are trying are best, but we can only understand questions that make sense. Try to format your question a bit differently after you check out StackOverflow's Help Center page on how to write a good question.

Comment: @IMMLGPRO1337420 question seems pretty clear to me

Comment: @charlietfl, yes the idea of making a checkbox is, but there are two other things. What specific type of style of checkbox does the OP want. And I don't understand why the OP has to create a checkbox with a div when you can create an input and set the type as a checkbox.

Comment: @IMMLGPRO1337420 perhaps you don't understand, however it is common practice these days for styling. Suggest ask for clarification from OP but overall others are understanding it also, In other word...try to not to speak for the community...and just ask clarification question as yourself

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make sense! What I'm trying to do is something like this: http://sv.tinypic.com/r/dcelb6/9. So the boxed are colored, and you can check them.

Answer (score 4):

> where the user can **choose** **colors** by checking the **colored boxes** to pick
>   the ones they want.

snippet here

```js
colors={'black-box':'black','grey-box':'grey','blue-box':'blue'}
var elements=document.getElementsByClassName('color-box')
function handler(el){
el[i].addEventListener('click',
function(e){
 if(e.target.className.split(' ')[1] in colors){
  document.getElementById('selector').style.background=    colors[e.target.className.split(' ')[1]]
    }
   for(var i=0;i<elements.length;++i){
    if(elements[i]!=e.target){elements[i].innerHTML=''}
    }
e.target.innerHTML=='✓'?e.target.innerHTML='':e.target.innerHTML='✓';
},false)
}
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;++i){
handler(elements)
}

//document.getElementsByClassName('color-box').forEach(handler)
```

```css
.color-box {
  color:white;
  font-size:20px;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;

  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 0.72917%;
  display: block;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.black-box {
  background: #000;
}

.grey-box {
  background: #9E9E9E;
}

.blue-box {
  background: #205DB1;
}
#selector{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-box black-box" >
        </div>
        <div class="color-box grey-box">
        </div>
        <div class="color-box blue-box">
        </div>
</div>
<div id='selector'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic example of how to implement it without JS https://plnkr.co/edit/tvamZjENZSLWnrtthDHP?p=preview

```
<style>
.checkbox > input[type="checkbox"] {  display: none; }
.checkbox > input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {margin-right: 10px; content: "[X]";}
.checkbox > input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {margin-right: 10px; content: "[ ]";}
</style>


<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="test">
  <label for="test">HELLO</label>
</div>
```

Note that i'm using `>` to indicate the immediate checkbox element descendant of `.checkbox` element, and the `+` selector for getting the next LABEL element sibling of that input

Answer (score 2):

This is a pure CSS one, using "*hidden*" `radio`set with their `label` colored

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d0nz1t31/3/)

```css
.radios{
  display:none;
}
.color-box {
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-top: 0.72917%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 7px 0.72917%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.black-box {
  background: #000;
}
.grey-box {
  background: #9E9E9E;
}
.blue-box {
  background: #205DB1;
}
.radios:checked + label{
  text-decoration:underline;
}
#rad1:checked ~ #result{
  background-color:black;
}
#rad2:checked ~ #result{
  background-color:#9E9E9E;
}
#rad3:checked ~ #result{
  background-color:#205DB1;
}
#result{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:2px orange solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="rad" class="radios">
  <label for="rad1" class="color-box black-box">Black</label>

  <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="rad" class="radios">
  <label for="rad2" class="color-box grey-box">Grey</label>

  <input type="radio" id="rad3" name="rad" class="radios">
  <label for="rad3" class="color-box blue-box">Blue</label>

  <hr>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```